# EF many to many one way add same item twice to child collection doesn't get saved

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, oneway

Thx for taking the time to read this. I've been looking for an answer to this problem for a week already and I'm running out of ideas...
This is the scenario:

The model:

```
public class Parent{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Child> ChildCollection{ get; set; }
}

public class Child {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set}
}
```

On Model creating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
            .HasMany(c => c.ChildCollection)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.ToTable("ParentToChildMapping");
                x.MapLeftKey("ParentId");
                x.MapRightKey("ChildId");
            }); 
}
```

Now the problem:

If I have a Parent object with a Child object in the collection and try to add a new object of same id to the child collection the DbContext doesn't "detect" the change and doesn't add a new entry in the mapping table.
But if I add a new Child (that doesn't exist in the collection) it does get added ok.

For Example:

```
{  
   var childId = Guid.Parse("cbd5bccc-b977-4861-870d-089994958cdf");
   var parent = new Parent { ChildCollection = new HashSet<Child>() };
   var context = new DBContext();
   var child = context.Childs.Single(c=>c.Id=childId);

   parent.ChildCollection.Add(child);
   context.Parents.Add(parent);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Then:

```
{
   var childId = Guid.Parse("cbd5bccc-b977-4861-870d-089994958cdf");
   var context = new DBContext();
   var parent = dbContext.Parents.Include(p=>p.ChildCollection).Single(p=>p.Id=parentId); // The id saved in the point before.
   var child = context.Childs.Single(c=>c.Id=childId);

   parent.ChildCollection.Add(child);
   // At this point parent.ChildCollection.Count() = 2
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The count of the collection is 2, which is fine. But save changes doesn't add the item. If I retrieve it back from the db using context again, it only returns 1 element in the collection.

Any thoughts are wellcome.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that they both have the same `Id`, so when it actually saves it just over writes the old value.

Comment: I think ycsum is right, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to add the same child to a parent **twice**, and this won't work. If you were successful, you would end up with something like the following in the database:

- one Child, Id = "cbd5bccc-b977-4861-870d-089994958cdf"
- one Parent, Id = "the-parent-id"
- **two** ParentToChildMappings, both had ParentId = "the-parent-id" and ChildId = "cbd5bccc-b977-4861-870d-089994958cdf"

which is not allowed for a relational database, because (ParentId, ChildId) is the primary key of ParentToChildMapping, and two rows in a table cannot have the same primary key.

Comment: I see what u mean, I'll create a new entity to hold both ids plus a primary key. I was afraid that was going to be the answer. Thx